# Table head does not load properly in jQuery dataTables

Tags: datatables

I am new to dataTables. When I initialize the datatable, it loads with default height and width, then it works fine! While loading, i could not find `search` and `pagelength` input boxes, but once the loading is completed, it is getting displayed. I would like to show search and pagelength boxes by default. Also I would like to show datatable contents only when it is fully loaded.
I have also attached the image when the datatable loads.

http://www.imagesup.net/di-3141473570613.png

My Code :

```js
 $('#user_list').dataTable({ 
      "bProcessing" : true,
      "bDestroy" : true,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bAutoHeight": false,
      "bLengthChange": true, "bJQueryUI": false,
      "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
          $('.tbodyy').show();
       },
       "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
          $('.tbodyy').show(); //i use it to show datatable only after loading data.
          //alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
       }
 });
```

Comment: What is the `.tbodyy` class applied to? I would assume `tbody` but you never know...

Comment: tbodyy is just for identification. I use it to show and hide.